# how to logout from front end when the session times out from backend?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, backbone.js, slim

I am using Slim Framework as a back end, and Backbone.js as a front-end framework. The application is created to allow users to submit a form and when they do, they will receive a mail/pdf receipt with certain data and it performs as mentioned below:

- User visits the website to request the receipt.
- The site asks them to login
- Once they do, their details (username, email, etc) are stored in sessions.
- When they submit the form using Backbone.js/Front-end through api calls, the data is received and receipts are generated.
- Details stored in session (username, email) are used while generating receipts.
- Once done, the receipts are mailed.

PROBLEM SCENARIO:

A user logs in, and leaves the application open for very long after filling some details of the form. The server side session times out but the front-end stays the same. The user then comes back and fill the rest of the form. However, since the session has timed out, the variable set in background (username, email) returns null, and the application either fails or does not work as expected.

I would like to inform the user about session expiration, and if no response comes, log them out from front-end. Also, if the user closes the browser/tab, i would like their session to logout.

Answer (score 2):

you only need a client side javascript to check if the user is still login in couple of seconds and your server side also must send to the client if him/her still login.

```
function checkIfLogin(){
 Backbone.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "URL HERE",
    data: "", // if you have data
    success: function(data){
      if(!data.isStillLogin){
        // statement if not login
      }else{
        // call again the checker
        setTimeout(checkIfLogin, 10000); 
      }
    }
 });
}
checkIfLogin();
```